# Corrupted excel file built with openxml only on production server

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

My excel file generated by one of my applications, is getting this error

The error is :

> “We Found A Problem with Some Content in Excel"

and it points me to a log file with the message:

> Repaired recods: View from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part.

Now to my .cs files where they are built:

First, this is how i start the workbook:

```
 using (var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelFilename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                {
                    var workbookPart = spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();

                    var openXmlExportHelper = new OpenXmlWriterHelper();
                    openXmlExportHelper.SaveCustomStylesheet(workbookPart);


                    var wkbook = workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                    var sheets = wkbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

                    // create worksheet 1
                    var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet1" };
                    sheets.Append(sheet);

                    using (var writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart))
                    {

                        writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                        writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());
                        var headerList = new string[dataTableExcel.Columns.Count];
                        for (var i = 0; i < dataTableExcel.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            headerList[i] = dataTableExcel.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                        }
                        //Create header row
                        writer.WriteStartElement(new Row());
                        for (int i = 0; i < headerList.Length; i++)
                        {
                            //header formatting attribute.  This will create a <c> element with s=2 as its attribute
                            //s stands for styleindex
                            var attributes = new OpenXmlAttribute[] { new OpenXmlAttribute("s", null, "2") }.ToList();
                            openXmlExportHelper.WriteCellValueSax(writer, headerList[i], CellValues.SharedString, attributes);

                        }
                        writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of Row tag

                        foreach(var element in lista)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(new Row());
                            foreach (var campo in element.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
                            {
                                var name = campo.Name;

                                openXmlExportHelper.WriteCellValueSax(writer, campo.GetValue(element) != null ? campo.GetValue(element).ToString() : string.Empty,
 campo.GetValue(element) != null ? RecuperaFormatoCampo(campo.GetValue(element).ToString()) : CellValues.InlineString,null,1,name);
                 
                            }
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
          
                        writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of SheetData
                        writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of worksheet
                        writer.Close();
                        openXmlExportHelper.CreateShareStringPart(workbookPart);
                    }

                }
```

Important, the savecustomstylesheet has some customizations like the following:

```
    //get a copy of the default excel style sheet then add additional styles to it
            var stylesheet = CreateDefaultStylesheet();

            // ***************************** Fills *********************************
            var fills = stylesheet.Fills;

            //header fills background color
            var fill = new Fill();
            var patternFill = new PatternFill();
            patternFill.PatternType = PatternValues.Solid;
            patternFill.ForegroundColor = new ForegroundColor { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("C8EEFF") };
            //patternFill.BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor() { Indexed = 64 };
            fill.PatternFill = patternFill;
            fills.AppendChild(fill);
            fills.Count = (uint)fills.ChildElements.Count;

            // *************************** numbering formats ***********************
            var nfs = stylesheet.NumberingFormats;
            //number less than 164 is reserved by excel for default formats
            uint iExcelIndex = 165;
            NumberingFormat nf;
            nf = new NumberingFormat();
            nf.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
            nf.FormatCode = @"[$-409]m/d/yy\ h:mm\ AM/PM;@";
            nfs.Append(nf);

            NumberingFormat nf2;
            nf2 = new NumberingFormat();
            nf2.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
            nf2.FormatCode = "\"R$\"#,##0.00;[Red]\"R$\"#,##0.00";
            nfs.Append(nf2);

            nfs.Count = (uint)nfs.ChildElements.Count;

            NumberingFormat nf3;
            nf3 = new NumberingFormat();
            
            nf3.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
            nf3.FormatCode = "\"\"#,##0.00;[Red]\"\"#,##0.00";
            nfs.Append(nf3);


            NumberingFormat nf4;
            nf4 = new NumberingFormat();
            nf4.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
            nf4.FormatCode = "@";
            nfs.Append(nf4);

            nfs.Count = (uint)nfs.ChildElements.Count;

            //************************** cell formats ***********************************
            var cfs = stylesheet.CellFormats;//this should already contain a default StyleIndex of 0

            var cf = new CellFormat();// Date time format is defined as StyleIndex = 1
            cf.NumberFormatId = nf.NumberFormatId;
            cf.FontId = 0;
            cf.FillId = 0;
            cf.BorderId = 0;
            cf.FormatId = 1;
            cf.ApplyNumberFormat = true;
            cfs.Append(cf);

            cf = new CellFormat();// Header format is defined as StyleINdex = 2
            cf.NumberFormatId = nf.NumberFormatId;
            cf.FontId = 0;
            cf.FillId = 2;
            cf.ApplyFill = true;
            cf.BorderId = 0;
            cf.FormatId = 0;
            cf.ApplyNumberFormat = true;
            cfs.Append(cf);
            
            ///**Style index = 3
            CellFormat cellFormat1 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)1,
                FontId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FillId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, 
                ApplyNumberFormat = true };
            cfs.Append(cellFormat1);

            ///**Style index = 4
            CellFormat cellFormatdecimal = new CellFormat()
            {
                NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)nf2.NumberFormatId,
                FontId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FillId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                ApplyNumberFormat = true
            };
            cfs.Append(cellFormatdecimal);

            //Style index = 5            
            CellFormat cellFormat5 = new CellFormat()
            {
                NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)nf3.NumberFormatId,
                FontId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FillId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                ApplyNumberFormat = true
            };
            cfs.Append(cellFormat5);

            //Style index = 6
            CellFormat cellFormat6 = new CellFormat()
            {
                NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)nf4.NumberFormatId,
                FontId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FillId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U,
                ApplyNumberFormat = true
            };
            cfs.Append(cellFormat6);

            cfs.Count = (uint)cfs.ChildElements.Count;

            var workbookStylesPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
            var style = workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;
            style.Save();

        }
```

And for the writecellvaluesax:

```
public void WriteCellValueSax(OpenXmlWriter writer, string cellValue, CellValues dataType, List<OpenXmlAttribute> attributes = null,int idFormat = 0,string columnname = "")
        {
            switch (dataType)
            {
                case CellValues.InlineString:
                    {
                        if (attributes == null)
                        {
                            attributes = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        }
                        attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "inlineStr"));
                        writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), attributes);
                        writer.WriteElement(new InlineString(new Text(cellValue)));
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        break;
                    }
                case CellValues.Number:
                    {
                        if (attributes == null)
                        {
                            attributes = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        }
                      
                        writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell() {DataType = CellValues.Number,StyleIndex = FormatoCampo(columnname,cellValue.Length)});
                        writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(cellValue));
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        break;
                    }
                case CellValues.SharedString:
                    {
                        if (attributes == null)
                        {
                            attributes = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        }
                        attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "s"));//shared string type
                        writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), attributes);
                        if (!_shareStringDictionary.ContainsKey(cellValue))
                        {
                            _shareStringDictionary.Add(cellValue, _shareStringMaxIndex);
                            _shareStringMaxIndex++;
                        }

                        //writing the index as the cell value
                        writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(_shareStringDictionary[cellValue].ToString()));


                        writer.WriteEndElement();//cell

                        break;
                    }
                case CellValues.Date:
                    {
                        if (attributes == null)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell() { DataType = CellValues.Number });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell() { DataType = CellValues.Number }, attributes);
                        }

                        writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(cellValue));

                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        break;
                    }
                case CellValues.Boolean:
                    {
                        if (attributes == null)
                        {
                            attributes = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        }
                        attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "b"));//boolean type
                        writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), attributes);
                        writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(cellValue == "True" ? "1" : "0"));
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        if (attributes == null)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell() { DataType = dataType });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell() { DataType = dataType }, attributes);
                        }
                        writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(cellValue));

                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        break;
                    }
            }

        }
```

I tried unziping the xlsx file to see if i could manually find anything weird, but nothing shows

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is this a [mre]?

Comment: Thanks, i guess it is not, since i coudnt even reproduce the error locally yet